# Sticky Footer Variable Height

Tags: html, css

The below code is to make a sticky footer at the bottom of the page (where if there is little content the footer sticks to the bottom of the page and where if there is a lot of content it sticks to the bottom of the content).

My problem with this code is when there is a lot of content my footer content wrapper is above the content.  This is because the footer is not becoming the size of its contents and showing its contents above itself.  I have tried numerous methods but I can't seem to get it to work.

Note: the footer is of variable height so I cannot use a constant to offset the footer by.

THE CSS:

```
body div#site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
body div#site-wrapper > * {
    display: table-row;
}
div#site-content-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
footer div#footerContentWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div id="site-wrapper">
    <div id="site-content-wrapper"> MAIN CONTENT </div>
    <footer><div id="footerContentWrapper" class="background">
         FOOTER CONTENT
    </div></footer>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/jhkL9bba/

Comment: is it possible that you can do a fiddle to show the issue?..also what  do you define as "a lot of content?"..a lot of content can mean different things example 80% or 70% of page is occupied by main content?

Comment: I'll add a fiddle now and what I mean by a lot of content is enough to make it scroll

Comment: Fiddle has been added now

Answer (score 0):

**Set width of footer div#footerContentWrapper  to be 10vh, example**

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
}
```

**and the remainder 85vh place as div#site-content-wrapper, example**

```
div#site-content-wrapper {
  position:relative;
    height: 85vh;
    background:#F00;
    border:solid blue;

}
```

take out  css footer styling

here is a a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/vz4cuzpr/

Limitations: you footer will increase/decrease a little **if** the user resize window.

Comment: okay.....Here is a try at it....I was thinking a javascript approach would be a good idea by capturing window resize event and do the necessary but this is a css approach

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the CSS below works.  It works because I have removed the absolute positioning of the footer wrapper thereby causing it to have the same height as the footer thereby removing my problem as it will be properly at the bottom instead of over the content

```
body div#site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
body div#site-wrapper > * {
    display: table-row;
}
div#site-content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
footer div#footerContentWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 50px 5px 50px;
}
```